# Can't type with selenium into contenteditable div displayed in IE8

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I encountered following problem while automating Sharepoint site using selenium 1 in IE8 browser. I can not type into  tag (Sharepoint people picker field) 
Below is the html code :

```
 <td sizcache="10" sizset="0">    
       <div tabIndex="0"
                title="People Picker"
                class="ms-inputuserfield"
                id="ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor_upLevelDiv"
                style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; background-color:window; width: 100%; height: 18px; color: windowtext;"
                contentEditable="true"
                onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw(this, 'ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor',3, true, event);"
                onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor');"
                onclick="onClickRw(true, true);"
                onblur="updateControlValue('ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor')"
                ondragstart="canEvt(event);"
                oncopy="docopy();"
                onpaste="dopaste();"
                onfocusin="this._fFocus=1;saveOldEntities('ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor_upLevelDiv')"
                onfocusout="this._fFocus=0;"
                name="upLevelDiv"
                AutoPostBack="0"
                onChange="updateControlValue('ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor')"
       />

       <textarea
               name="ctl$ctl00$pePeopleEditor$downlevelTextBox"
               title="People Picker"
               class="ms-input" id="ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor_downlevelTextBox"
               style="position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none; height:20px;"
               onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw(this, 'ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor', 3,true, event);"
               onkeyup="onKeyUpRw('ctl00_ctl00_pePeopleEditor');"
               rows="1"
               cols="20"
               AutoPostBack="0"
       />
</td>
```

I tried to put the text into that field using selenium functions as follows but none of them work out:

```
self.selenium.click(div_locator)
self.selenium.type_keys(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press_native(65)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

self.selenium.fire_event(div_locator,"focus")
self.selenium.type_keys(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press_native(65)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

self.selenium.click_at(div_locator,"") 
self.selenium.type_keys(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press(div_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press_native(65)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

self.selenium.click(textbox_locator)
self.selenium.type(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.type_keys(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press_native(65)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

self.selenium.fire_event(textbox_locator,"focus")
self.selenium.type(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.type_keys(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press(textbox_locator, "string")
self.selenium.key_press_native(65
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

self.selenium.set_cursor_position(textbox,-1)
self.selenium.key_press(textbox_locator,  "\\13")
self.selenium.key_press_native(10)
self.selenium.key_press_native(65)
```

Note also that there is no problem with this field on FF and IE6

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this Sharepoint people picker field ?

Alek

Comment: What type of locator are you using? Xpath or CSS?

Comment: I tried both types, but none of them work out.

Comment: To clarify: Selenium succeed in finding textarea and div tags by using both css and xpath locators, however the text doesn't appear inside the field.

Comment: And you are sure that its not a page load issue? Like you enter the text before the page loads completely and when the page loads it might be resetting the text area to empty? Can you also put the locator you tried?

Comment: I am almost sure that it is not load page issue - I use time break and ajax wait too. Below selectors I used :

  sel.type("css=div[id$='_pePeopleEditor_upLevelDiv']", "Test")
        sel.type("css=textarea[id$='pePeopleEditor_downlevelTextBox']", "Test")
        sel.type("//textarea[contains(@id,'pePeopleEditor_downlevelTextBox')]", "Test")
        sel.type("//div[contains(@id,'pePeopleEditor_upLevelDiv')]", "Test")

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find resolution for my problem, however it seems that this is a limitation of selenium 1.

According to [David Burns](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/why-should-i-move-to-selenium-2.html) one way to overcome this problem is to use Selenium 2. Indeed I can type into this field on IE8 with Selenium 2.
David also indicated way to overcome problem with tags where contenteditable is set to true:

> *I have started moving my Internet Explorer Selenium Tests to use the WebDriver API to test the Editor component of our site. This is one of the hardest areas to automate with Selenium 1 because its using contentEditable on a div. I managed to test this using the components JavaScript API to inject HTML and then manipulate it and then use the API to get the HTML out again and check that it is correct.*

To sum up I can:

- switch to Selenium 2 with Webdriver
- use JavaScript API components to
  inject the original HTML